# How to change time format to hh:mm:a using xlsx in angular

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, export-to-excel, time-format

I'm using exportAsExcelFile for JSON data to excel in the angular application. When exporting, the time columns are getting default time format like this 12:00, When I double-clicked each cell of excel file then time shows 12:00:am format. But I wanted the time format to be 12:00:am download in excel.
Is there any way that I can download the time in this(12:00:am) format without excel cell formatting? If Is this possible? please suggest the solution.

Thank you

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I am facing the same problem, but I pass only the `HH: MM` only but in this excel to include format as `AM/PM`, any other solutions are found. I use excel without that format include one single quote for entering hours and minutes same way to use: use these functions to

```
 this.exportCSVtable[i]['Hours Worked'] = this.RemoveHtmlElement(this.exportCSVtable[i]['hoursWorkedTotal'])
                    delete this.exportCSVtable[i]['hoursWorkedTotal'];


RemoveHtmlElement(HoursMin`enter code here`utes) {
        var HHMM = "'"+HoursMinutes;
        return HHMM;
    }
```